# Find command which will give file size info etc

Tags: unix, terminal, find, ls

I am want to find all jars files but to get their all the info ls -alrt will also give me i.e. filesize and datetime stamp.

I try

```
find . -iname *.jar | ls -alrt
```

but obviously this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ls` will not read file names from `stdin`. You have to pass file name as argument to `ls`. Like this:

```
find . -iname *.jar -exec ls -alrt {} \;
```

(OR)

```
find . -iname *.jar -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lhrt
```